# How can i use LINQ to pass highlighted Cells to another DataGridView?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

Is there any way to use a LINQ style query to pass the Value of the highlighted Cells(without ComboBox) to another DataGridView? In the figure below, the cells to be transferred are marked.

Many thanks in advance for your ideas!

```
       private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (!(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null))
                    {
                        var cr = 
                        dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = 
                        Color.Red; 
                        var cg = 
                        dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = 
                        Color.LawnGreen;

                        dataGridView3.Rows.Add(cr);
                        dataGridView3.Rows.Add(cg); 

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Is your question about whether you can use linq to query for rows with a certain style of the cells?

Comment: I’m still looking for a possibility to transfer the Value of marked Cells to another DataGridView. 
I thought it would be easier to solve the problem with a LINQ query. Other solutions may be suggested by any interested party, however.

Comment: Does the other DataGridView have the same columns? Are you looking to copy the entire row, or only the highlighted value?

Comment: I'm looking to copy only the highlighted values to another DataGridView. Yes, the other dataGridView3 has the same columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's some sample code using linq which will copy values where a cell has a certain background color. The key to using Linq is the [Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.8) method which can take non-generic `IEnumerable` and turn it into a generic `IEnumerable` so we can use the linq syntax. It also uses the `Select` overload which includes a parameter for the index, so you can easily index into the second data grid to get to the correct row / column.

```
var linqable = dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select((r, y) => new
{
    row = r,
    rowNum = y,
    cells = r.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select((a, b) =>
    new
    {
        cell = a,
        cellNum = b
    })
});

foreach(var row in linqable)
{
    foreach(var cellWithRed in row.cells.Where(x => x.cell.Style.BackColor == Color.Red))
    {
        dataGridView3.Rows[row.rowNum].Cells[cellWithRed.cellNum].Value = cellWithRed.cell.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  But how can i „easily“ index dataGridView2 to get the correct row / colum? However,you’ve done a great job, Zeph!!

Comment: If dataGridView2 is the source, you have the index for the row/column based on the rowNum property and the cellNum property (both are just names I used in the anonymous types). The `Cast` and `Select` methods work on the existing order of the row/cells, so the index (second parameter of the select method) is also the index of the row in the grid or the cell in the row.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, Zeph!  : )